# It is possible to accessing FocusState's value outside of the body of a View

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, viewmodel

I want to deport my @FocusState into my viewModel:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Text", text: $viewModel.textField)
                .focused(viewModel.$hasFocus)
            Button("Set Focus") {
                viewModel.hasFocus = true
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textField: String = ""
    @FocusState var hasFocus: Bool
}
```

But when I launch my app, i have this SwiftUI warning:

> runtime: SwiftUI: Accessing FocusState's value outside of the body of
> a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value
> and will not update.

And in this case, my binding is never changed.

My question is: It is possible to use FocusState in a viewModel?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is in-view wrapper (same as `State`). But it is possible to map it to published property like in below approach.

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @FocusState var hasFocus: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Text", text: $viewModel.textField)
                .focused($hasFocus)
                .onChange(of: viewModel.hasFocus) {
                    hasFocus = $0
                }
                .onChange(of: hasFocus) {
                    viewModel.hasFocus = $0
                }
            Button("Set Focus") {
                viewModel.hasFocus = true
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textField: String = ""
    @Published var hasFocus: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: This solution worked very smoothly for me as I was stuck with the same problem.  Now I am able to tidy up my code.  Thank you.

Comment: Works good, but sometimes it's still more convenient to use UIKit wrapper to hide the keyboard than too look for the views to attach a gesture / adding a button for whole screen sadly :(